# x64 Assembly Optimization

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, masm, portable-executable

I am trying to optimize several assembly procedures for size, I am not concerned about the speed.
The optimizations I am familiar with are situations as follows:

```
;the following two lines
    mov rbp, rsp
    add rbp, 50h
;can be changed to
    lea rbp, [rsp+50h]
```

**What other optimizations I can use to reduce the number of bytes in the following procedure?**
I am not asking anyone to fully optimize this procedure, just point out where I can improve.

```
;get procedure address
asmGetProc proc
push rcx                    ;pointer to function name
push rdx                    ;DllBase address (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER pointer)
push r8                     ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY
push r9                     ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->NumberOfNames
                            ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals[r9]

push rbx                    ;saved pointer to function name

push r10                    ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNames
                            ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals
                            ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfFunctions

mov rbx, rcx                ;save the function name pointer to rax

mov r8d, [rdx+3ch]          ;IMAGE_DOS_HEADER->e_lfanew (DWORD) (Offset to IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)
add r8, rdx                 ;add DllBase to the e_lfanew offset
add r8, 88h                 ;18h - IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64->OptionalHeader (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64) 18h bytes
                            ;70h - skip entire IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 structure
                            ;r8 points to the IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY structure
mov r8d, [r8]               ;IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY->VirtualAddress (DWORD)
add r8, rdx                 ;add DllBase to VirtualAddress (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)

mov r9d, [r8+18h]           ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->NumberOfNames
mov r10d, [r8+20h]          ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNames (DWORD)
add r10, rdx                ;add DllBase to AddressOfNames (DWORD)
for_each_function:
    ;decrement function name counter
    dec r9

    ;load current index of AddressOfNames into r11
    lea rcx, [r10 + 4 * r9]     ;AddressOfNames[i] - function string RVA (relative virtual address)
    mov ecx, [rcx]              ;r11d is the AddressOfName[r9] RVA (DWORD)
    add rcx, rdx                ;add DllBase to string RVA DWORD

    call asmHsh                 ;hash the function name
    cmp rax, rbx                ;compare the function name hash with the passed hash
jnz for_each_function           ;jump to top of loop is not a match


;r8  - export directory
;r9  - function name counter
;r10 - AddressOfNameOrdinals / AddressOfFunctions array
;rax - final point to function
mov r10d, [r8+24h]          ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals (DWORD)
add r10, rdx                ;add DllBase to AddressOfNameOrdinals DWORD
mov r9w, [r10+2*r9]         ;AddressOfNameOrdinals[2*r9] - (2*r9 = 2 bytes * function name counter)

mov r10d, [r8+1ch]          ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfFunctions (DWORD)
add r10, rdx                ;add DllBase to AddressOfFunctions DWORD
mov eax, [r10+r9*4]         ;AddressOfFunctions[4*r9] - (4*r9 = 4 bytes * function ordinal)
add rax, rdx                ;add DllBase to function ordinal RVA DWORD

pop r10
pop rbx
pop r9
pop r8
pop rdx
pop rcx

ret                         ;return from procedure
asmGetProc endp
```

EDIT: Added asmHsh (my bad)

```
;hash function (djb2)
asmHsh proc
;rcx - null terminated function name
push rcx
push rdx

mov rax, 5381d
hl:
    mov rdx, rax
    shl rax, 5
    add rax, rdx
    xor al, [rcx]
    inc rcx
;check for null termination
mov dl, [rcx]
cmp dl, 00h
jne short hl         

pop rdx
pop rcx
ret

asmHsh endp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing assembly for space in 64-bit mode one should: (1) use **DWORD** width when that suffices (less prefixes); (2) stick to the old X86 registers **eax-edx / esi / edi / ebp** (tighter encoding).

Hopefully what's done below illustrates the idea.  ML64 assembled the original routines to 135 bytes and the modified version to 103 bytes.

Examples of changes: (1) used **rbp / rsi / rdi** instead of **r8 / r9 / r10**; (2) shrunk instruction sequences that could be accomplished via multi-component address modes; (3) used **DWORD dec** where the data is known to be 32-bits; (4) used **IMUL** in place of shift/add.

" **;-** " is in front of removed lines " **;## delta** " is appended to added lines, where delta is the byte difference the new code produced.  No attempt was made to adjust the comments.

```
;hash function (djb2)
asmHsh proc
;rcx - null terminated function name
push rcx
;-push rdx ;## -1

mov rax, 5381d
hl:
;-  mov rdx, rax
;-  shl rax, 5
;-  add rax, rdx
    imul rax,rax,33 ;## -6
    xor al, [rcx]
    inc rcx
;check for null termination
;-mov dl, [rcx]
;-cmp dl, 00h
cmp byte ptr [rcx], 00h ;## -2
jne short hl         

;-pop rdx ;## -1
pop rcx
ret
asmHsh endp

;get procedure address
asmGetProc proc
push rcx                    ;pointer to function name
push rdx                    ;DllBase address (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER pointer)
;-push r8                    ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY
push rbp ;## -1
;-push r9                     ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->NumberOfNames
push rsi ;## -1
                            ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals[r9]

push rbx                    ;saved pointer to function name

;-push r10                    ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNames
push rdi ;## -1
                            ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals
                            ;pointer to IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfFunctions

mov rbx, rcx                ;save the function name pointer to rax

;-mov r8d, [rdx+3ch]          ;IMAGE_DOS_HEADER->e_lfanew (DWORD) (Offset to IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)
mov ebp, [rdx+3ch] ;## -1
;-add r8, rdx                 ;add DllBase to the e_lfanew offset
;-add r8, 88h                 ;18h - IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64->OptionalHeader (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64) 18h bytes
;-                            ;70h - skip entire IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 structure
;-                            ;r8 points to the IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY structure
;-mov r8d, [r8]               ;IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY->VirtualAddress (DWORD)
mov ebp, [rbp+rdx+88h] ;## -5
;-add r8, rdx                 ;add DllBase to VirtualAddress (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)
add rbp, rdx ;## 0

;-mov r9d, [r8+18h]           ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->NumberOfNames
mov esi, [rbp+18h] ;## -1
;-mov r10d, [r8+20h]          ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNames (DWORD)
mov edi, [rbp+20h] ;## -1
;-add r10, rdx                ;add DllBase to AddressOfNames (DWORD)
add rdi, rdx ;## 0
for_each_function:
    ;decrement function name counter
;-  dec r9
    dec esi ;## -1

    ;load current index of AddressOfNames into r11
;-  lea rcx, [r10 + 4 * r9]     ;AddressOfNames[i] - function string RVA (relative virtual address)
;-  mov ecx, [rcx]              ;r11d is the AddressOfName[r9] RVA (DWORD)
    mov ecx, [rdi + 4 * rsi] ;## -3
    add rcx, rdx                ;add DllBase to string RVA DWORD

    call asmHsh                 ;hash the function name
    cmp rax, rbx                ;compare the function name hash with the passed hash
jnz for_each_function           ;jump to top of loop is not a match


;r8  - export directory
;r9  - function name counter
;r10 - AddressOfNameOrdinals / AddressOfFunctions array
;rax - final point to function
;-mov r10d, [r8+24h]          ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals (DWORD)
mov edi, [rbp+24h];## -1
;-add r10, rdx                ;add DllBase to AddressOfNameOrdinals DWORD
add rdi, rdx; ## 0
;-mov r9w, [r10+2*r9]         ;AddressOfNameOrdinals[2*r9] - (2*r9 = 2 bytes * function name counter)
mov si, [rdi+2*rsi] ;## -1

;-mov r10d, [r8+1ch]          ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfFunctions (DWORD)
mov edi, [rbp+1ch] ;## -1
;-add r10, rdx                ;add DllBase to AddressOfFunctions DWORD
add rdi, rdx ;## 0
;-mov eax, [r10+r9*4]         ;AddressOfFunctions[4*r9] - (4*r9 = 4 bytes * function ordinal)
mov eax, [rdi+rsi*4] ; ## -1
add rax, rdx                ;add DllBase to function ordinal RVA DWORD

;-pop r10
pop rdi ; ## -1
pop rbx
;-pop r9
pop rsi
;-pop r8
pop rbp ;## -1
pop rdx
pop rcx

ret                         ;return from procedure
asmGetProc endp
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise that using the x86 registers was more efficient. For completeness I've added asmHsh to the question.

Comment: No problem.  Since you provided asmHsh I updated my answer, and took a crack at shrinking asmHsh as well.